# Clickable View in Compose LazyColumn consumes scroll event

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've a Compose `LazyColumn` which contains `AndroidView`s each of which contains clickable and non-clickable views. When scrolling non-clickable area (the `TextView` view), the `LazyColumn` can be scrolled. However, when trying to scroll by starting to press down from the clickable area (the `Button` view), the `LazyColumn` **cannot** be scrolled, as if the `Button` consumes the event without telling the `LazyColumn`. Is there a workaround for this?

This happens only when using Android View within Compose. However, when the items are Composable instead of View, it works as expected. So does when a clickable Composable is used within a `RecyclerView`, the clickable Composable doesn't prevent the `RecyclerView` to scroll.

This is the simple version of what I talk about:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    items(100) { idx ->
        AndroidView(
            factory = { ctx ->
                LinearLayout(ctx).apply {
                    orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                    addView(TextView(ctx).apply {
                        text = "Non-clickable view $idx"
                    })
                    addView(android.widget.Button(ctx).apply {
                        text = "Clickable view $idx"
                        setOnClickListener {}
                    })
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Compose version: 1.0.5
Kotlin version: 1.5.31

Comment: I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) it to Compose issue tracker

Comment: @PhilipDukhov okay

Comment: When you only have 10 items in the list that consist only of buttons, on an average sized phone, that isn't enough items to reach the bottom of the screen to enable scrolling. Increase the number to a larger count and you'll see that scrolling works. If it still doesn't work, you must be using an older version of Compose. This has been tested on 1.1.0-beta03.

Comment: @Johann thanks for the comment, I've increased the number to 100 to make the question more clear. Btw it's just a sample code that can be tried at home (can be reproduced by the readers), my actual code has more items, each item is taller than this sample.

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted? Does it work on your device? What version of Compose are you using?

Comment: @Johann will reply in your post

Comment: Updated the question with the version @Johann

Comment: @fikr4n it's strange that you can reproduce it with **1.0.5** because I can only reproduce it on the latest beta. Some of your other dependencies may depend on beta version. The easies way to check is navigate to `AndroidView` source code, select file in project view and there you can see the used library version

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I've checked it in project view, it's in classes.jar of version 1.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. First, you don't have enough items in the list. Your sample code shows only 10 items. If you run that on an average sized phone, there are not enough items to fill the screen to allow for scrolling.

Even after adding more items, you should also set the LazyColumn's width/height. Set it to `fillMaxSize`, otherwise it defaults to wrapping to the content's width, which in your case is just the width of the button. If you don't fill the width and you only have the buttons in the list, you won't be able to scroll when you scroll outside of the buttons:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                items(20) { idx ->
                    AndroidView(
                        factory = { ctx ->
                            LinearLayout(ctx).apply {
                                orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                                addView(TextView(ctx).apply { text = "Item $idx" })
                                addView(android.widget.Button(ctx).apply { text = "Button"; setOnClickListener {} })
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not solving the author problem here. It's not about `LazyColumn` not scrolling on the right side of the screen. It's about it's not scrolling when start scroll point is on a `android.widget.Button`

Comment: I only tried running the content of `setContent` of your code. You shouldn't include activity part in your answers in the first place, as this is redundant. Anyway your full code doesn't compile at all, because of `ComponentActivity can only be called from within the same library group prefix`, and after updating it to `AppCompatActivity`, it doesn't solves the author issue, as you can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F960ZLVuBwk)

Comment: Or if you think that using some specific activity type is a must for your answer to work, you should explain why, and what is required for it to work, as on my machine it doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov for proving by video, you're awesome. @ Johann Btw I tried a new project and copy-paste this code, it's magically working, not sure why, I'm currently trying to figure out what is the difference between the new project and my existing project, as it doesn't work in my existing project.

Comment: What version of Compose are you using?

Comment: @fikr4n your issue is not reproducable on `1.0.5`, and only reproducable on latest `1.1.0-beta04`. Johann's answer changes nothing in both cases: it works fine on stable without the fix and doesn't work on beta with the fix.